# AWS lambda api gateway error “Malformed Lambda proxy response”

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

My AWS ApiGateway invokes this lambda function :

```
const handler = (event, context) => {

    const theResponse = {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "isBase64Encoded": false,
        "headers": {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        "body": "hello, world"
    };

    switch (event.httpMethod) {
        case 'GET':
            theResponse["body"] = `method ${event.httpMethod} detected`;
            break;
        default:
            theResponse["statusCode"] = 404;
            theResponse["body"] = `Unsupported method ${event.httpMethod} detected`;
            break;
    }
    return theResponse;
};


module.exports = {
    handler,
};
```

Any thoughts to why this errors with :

```
{"message": "Internal server error"}
Received response. Status: 200, Integration latency: 344 ms
Endpoint response body before transformations: null
Execution failed due to configuration error: Malformed Lambda proxy response
Method completed with status: 502
```

I tried replacing `return (theResponse);` with  `return JSON.stringify(theResponse);` but this also returns the same error.

However if I replace `return theResponse;` with `return {"statusCode":200, "body":"hello, world"};`  then the API executes without errors.

Looks to me like a lamda_proxy integration issue but I can't see why. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Bearrider!

I guess it is related to the way you are building your response object:

- Try stringify only the body attribute:

  ```
      case 'GET':
          theResponse["body"] = JSON.stringify(`method ${event.httpMethod} detected`);
          break;
      default:
          theResponse["statusCode"] = 404;
          theResponse["body"] = JSON.stringify(`Unsupported method ${event.httpMethod} detected`);
          break;
      }
  ```

Comment: JSON.stringify did not work but changing 
`module.exports = {
    handler,
};
`
 to  ```exports.handler ``` worked. But I am not sure why. I thought the two are syntactically equal?